# Problem processing route in Ember.js app when building and running app in Android studio emulator

Tags: android-studio, ember.js, capacitor

Trying to build and run an Ember app with Capacitor on virtual device in Android studio. Build and installation goes fine until the app is launched and stops when trying to process a spesific route. The problem only occurs when building from windows, no problem on Mac. The app is communicating with a jsonapi.

Error message in chrome device inspector: "Error while processing route [routename]"

I have tried with physical device connected getting the same message. Also tried with Genymotion plugin.

Capture of browser console:
[chrome console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKi3G.png)

And this is what logcat is giving:
[logcat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJehF.png)

I also have some errors reported from the IDE (Android Studio) not related to running the Emulator but occurs when opening the IDE:
[Android Studio errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSms3.png). In case this has something to do with it.

Solution in this case:
Had to reinstall node js with another older version. Did an npm cache clean and built the app all over again. Also made sure to open the project with npx cap open android.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to ember+stackoverflow!!!!

any chance you can capture the error and stack from the browser console?

Comment: Thanks @NullVoxPopuli! I added some captures in the question description.

Comment: can you copy the text to the post (including stack trace)? (just in case folks' networks have imgur blocked?)

Comment: I managed to figure it out. Thanks anyways.

Comment: any chance you can post an answer with what the solution was?